# Hiding a DIV in a JQuery Overlay Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Taking from the code found here: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html

I got my popup window to work and everything but I wanted to prevent my header from displaying in the overlay popup window.  I've added **$('#header').hide();** to the script below but its not working. Sorry Im not too familiar with javascript. Any help would be great!

```
$(function () { // if the function argument is given to overlay,   
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({
        mask: 'grey',
        effect: 'apple',
        onBeforeLoad: function () {
            // grab wrapper element inside content 
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            // load the page specified in the trigger   
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
            $('#header').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Formatting your code readably makes it easier for you to have error-free code, and easier for people to help you with your code. I've taken the liberty of running your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ for you on this occasion.

Comment: Without the relevant parts of your HTML, it's hard for people to help you. For instance, do you really have an element with `id="header"`?

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for cleaning the code. I just copied it from the Jquery website. Yes I do have my header info surrounded by a <div id="header">content</div>

Comment: @izuriel, its not giving me errors but its not hiding the header portion like I want it too.

Comment: @Kim: No, it clearly wasn't just a copy-and-paste, the code was *all over* the place in terms of indentation, line breaks, etc. The code on that site is perfectly well formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick test, and I think the issue is that you're trying to hide the header before it renders on the page. The overlay configuration has another event called onLoad, which would be a better place to ensure that the loading of the external content has happened.

Try this code:

```
$(function() {     
    // if the function argument is given to overlay,   
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
    $("a[rel]").overlay({
        mask: 'grey',
        effect: 'apple',
        onBeforeLoad: function() {             
            // grab wrapper element inside content 
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
            // load the page specified in the trigger   
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));  
            //at this point, the page is still loading the external content, so it's not available to hide yet
        },
        onLoad: function() {
            $('#header').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I plugged your code in. It strips away the header in the background page but not in the popup window, Any way to just remove the header from the pop up window and not the previous page?

Comment: If both the background page and the popup window have an element with an ID of 'header', then that's going to be an issue (IDs are supposed to be unique). Are you able to change the ID of the pop up header?

Comment: Actually, if you just want to see this work, you can replace $('#header').hide() with $('#overlay #header').hide() . I stand by my first comment with regards making unique IDs, but that should work just to prove the concept. This second form works because the overlay has an ID of 'overlay'.

Comment: Hey @pkhan thanks a lot for taking the time to help! Replacing $('#header').hide() with $('#overlay #header').hide() worked like a charm! Sorry for the vagueness with my post and I appreciate you working with me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, but two things:

1. If you want to do this every time, it's not dynamic. So put it in your CSS file.
2. You define this in "onBeforeLoad", so it is already "hide". Maybe there is a function would works better in this case.